# Resize my divs dynamically

Tags: html, resize

I have this code:

```
(array) $array_size=sizeof($data_for_analog_meter);

    for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i ++)
    {
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="la-<?=$i?>" class="la <?=$i?>" value='<?= $aa[$i];?>'></input>
        <div id="content-two-<?=$i?>" class="content">
            <div id="chart1_<?=$i?>"  class="jqplot-target"></div>
        </div>
        <?

    }
```

And now, i'm trying to resize my divs dinamically, as long as I add new charts.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any css or javascript already written to help you with this?

Comment: only this:.jqplot-target {
 width:300px;
 height: 200px;
}

.content{
 float:right;
 display: inline-block;
}

Comment: so you're basically trying to add a dynamic amount of divs to another div?

Comment: yes. like this:<div class="box two left">
<input type="hidden" id="la-<?=$i?>" class="la <?=$i?>" value='<?= $aa[$i];?>'></input>
        <div id="content-two-<?=$i?>" class="content">
            <div id="chart1_<?=$i?>"  class="jqplot-target"></div>
        </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to add multiple 'chart-divs' into the 'content-div'. Please correct me if that is wrong. That means you need to put your content-div out of your loop, to start with.

```
<div id="content">
<?php
   for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
?>
<div id="chart1_<?= $i ?>"  class="chart"></div>         
<?
   }
?>
</div> <!-- end div content -->
```

with the following css as an absolute minimum applied (fixed value is just an example) :

```
#content { width:500px; }
.chart { float:left; width:auto; }
```

Comment: I want add multiple 'content-div' into the 'box two left'.
is the same, right?  
<div class="box two left">
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++)
{
?>
<div id="content-two-<?=$i?>" class="content">
   <div id="chart1_<?=$i?>"  class="jqplot-target"></div>
</div>       
<?
   }
?>
</div>

Comment: it is the same principle indeed, just different naming. Try it out!

Comment: And if i want to add not more than 6 divs, displaying 3 on top, and another 3 below the previous 3?

Comment: in this case, edit the css to the following 
.chart { float:left; width:150px; }

Comment: that way 3 divs will be able to display next to eachother, but because the fourth one can't fit the outer-div (450 px + 150 px > 500 px) , the next chart-div will be below the previous three.